# Visiting Canada by land and back

Tags: usa, canada, new-zealand-citizens

My wife and I are New Zealand citizens and Mexico residents. We are driving across the US and thinking about traveling into Canada from Michigan and back into the US at Niagara falls or thereabouts.

I found a page on the Canada immigration website suggesting that an "ETA" isn't required for NZ citizens when entering by land, however reading further all references are to flying in and requiring the ETA. Is it correct that the ETA is not needed?

We have US B1/B2 visas with I-94 permits issued at the US/Mexico border. Am I right to assume these are just as valid when re-entering the US at the US/Canada border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct that the ETA is not needed?

Yes.  ETA is required only of air passengers.

> Am I right to assume these are just as valid when re-entering the US at the US/Canada border?

Yes.  You don't actually need an I-94 when arriving at the US border, but having one may make your entry smoother.  It's common for the I-94 to be reused if you haven't traveled beyond "contiguous territory," which you will not have done.  "Contiguous territory" comprises both Mexico and Canada.

If for some reason they decide you need a new I-94, it will only cost $6 per person.

Comment: Thanks @phoog. I have a feeling our I-94 is about to expire but we'll probably need to renew that when we enter the US from Mexico anyway.  I just wasn't sure whether the I-94 was a Mexico/US border thing only, or if it was required on the northern border also.

Comment: @Midavalo the I-94 is issued to virtually all nonimmigrants when they enter the US through any port of entry.  It comes in different forms; those entering by air don't get a piece of paper; instead there is a database record that they can retrieve from https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov and print out.